# A car company wants to ensure its newest model can stop in less than 450 ft when traveling at 60 mph. What is the rate of deceleration?

Tags: calculus

**Edit: This question involves derivatives, please read my prior work!**

This question has me stumped.

> A car company wants to ensure its newest model can stop in less than 450  ft when traveling at  60  mph. If we assume constant deceleration, find the value of deceleration that accomplishes this.

First, from the instructions, I believe...

$f'(x)=(5280/60)-ax=88-ax$

$f''(x)=-a$

I also believe $f(x)={\int}f'(x)dx=88x-a{\int}x=88x-a\frac{x^2}{2}$, because `a` is known to be constant.

Where I'm lost is what comes next. I can compute `a` and `x` in terms of each other at `f(x)=450`, but this doesn't seem to get me closer to the answer. Neither does the fact that $f^{-1}(450)=x$. What am I missing here? Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$a = \frac {dv}{dt}$ and $v = \frac {dx}{dt}$

By the chain rule $a = \frac {dv}{dx}\frac {dx}{dt} = v\frac {dv}{dx}$

$\int a\ dx = \int v\ dv\\
ax = \frac 12 v^2\\
a = \frac {v^2}{2x}$

But this is the minimum value of $a.$

$a \ge \frac {88^2}{900}$

Alternative....

$a = \frac {dv}{dt}\\
v = \frac {dx}{dt}$

$v(t) = v_0 - at = 88 - at\\
x(t) = 88 t - \frac 12 a t^2$

The vehicle comes to a stop at time $t = t^*$
$v(t^*) = 0\\
t^* = \frac {88}{a}\\
x(t^*) = 88\cdot \frac {88}{a} - \frac 12 a \frac {(88)^2}{a^2} = \frac {(88)^2}{2a} < 450\\
a > \frac {88^2}{900}$

Comment: Looking for an answer that specifically uses the derivatives I've provided. The question is here: https://openstax.org/books/calculus-volume-1/pages/4-10-antiderivatives, questions 509-513, which I completed successfully, are provided for context.

Comment: I have given you an alternative, albeit less elegant.

Comment: Make sure you keep you distances straight from time.  I like $x$ for distance and $t$ for time.  $s$ is also fine for distances.  But using $x$ for time always makes me a little nervous.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I believe the solution is rather simple. We have however been given not a fixed distance but an upper constraint on the distance to be travelled before it stops. Therefore, I will derive a simple equation of motion and use it to compute the dece;eration required. First of all, we are farmiliar with the fact that $a = \frac{v - u}{t}$ and $s = \frac{v + u}{2}$. From the first relation, $t = \frac{v - u}{a}.$ Substituting this into the second relation yields $s = \frac{v + u}{2}\frac{v - u}{a} = \frac{v^{2} - u^{2}}{2a}$. Therefore, $v^{2} = u^{2} + 2as$. Substituting the given values into our derived relation with $v = 0$, $u^{2} = -2as$
$3600 = -2(450)\cdot a$. $a = -4$. Hence, the deceleration for it to travel the $450$m would be $4ms^{-2}$. However, to stop at less than $450$m, it would have to decelerate at a higher rate. Hence the solution is $a >  4ms^{-2}$.

Comment: Looking specifically for answers that use derivatives, sorry.

Comment: Ok, @sent1nel I'll formulate one then.

Answer (score 0):

Since acceleration is constant we get that $$\frac{dv}{dt}=a\implies v = at+v_0$$ where $v_0$ is the initial velocity. In our case we are starting at $60\text{ mph}$ which is $88\text{ ft/s}$. To go from $88\text{ ft/s}$ to $0\text{ ft/s}$ requires $t=-\frac{88}{a}\text{ seconds}$.

From our expression for velocity we get that $$\frac{dx}{dt}=at+v_0\implies x=\frac{1}{2}at^2+v_0t+x_0$$ where $x_0$ is our initial position. We are trying to stop in $450\text{ ft}$ so we can let $x_0=0$ and $x=450$. Plugging everything in we get $$450=\frac{1}{2}\frac{88^{2}}{a}+ -\frac{88^2}{a}=-\frac{1}{2}\frac{88^2}{a}\implies a=-\frac{88^2}{900}$$